# How to pass modelform instance fields that are not intended for user input to template in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using formsets to pass several modelforms with existing model instances to a template. I'd like to do something in the template for each form depending on the value of a model field (let's call it field_check) for that instance. Field_check is not intended for user input and a required field.

If I include field_check into my form without rendering it, I can easily access its value. But then after submitting the form Django complains that field_check is required.

What is the recommended way to access the value of field_check without including it as an input field or running into the required field problem?

**Models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_check = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user_input_field = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    some_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            'user_input_field',
            'field_check', #having this field here creates problems, since it's not intended for user input
        ]

MyFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(MyModel, form = MyModelForm, extra=0)
```

**Views.py**

```
def myview(request):
    this_type = 1
    formset = MyFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(some_type = this_type))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return render(request, 'some_other_template.html')
    context = {'formset':formset}
    return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', context)
```

**Template**

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{form.id}

        # here is the part where I check for the value of field_check
        {% if form.field_check == 'Some value' %}
            Some text
        {% else %}
            Some other text
        {% endif %}

        {{form.user_input_field}}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `form.instance.field_check` would work if you are updating some instances. If they are passed as initial data on the other hand it would be a lot more complicated.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thanks, it's clear to me how to update particular instances. In my case the fields are filled with initial data by some backend logic and I want to access their value in the template. I was wondering, maybe there is some way to pass information along with the form and somehow declare it as 'not for user input', or some other more or less straightforward way.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Ah, now I understand. Wow, it works, exactly what I needed. Thank you for your help!